# What is this sum equal to? $\sigma(n)=\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{i^n j^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

I have recently come across the following sum, taken over all positive integers $i$ and $j$ such that $i \neq j$:

$$
\sigma(n)=\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{i^n j^n},
$$

where $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$.

Can this somehow be written in terms of the Riemann Zeta function? Is there already a zeta function of this kind?

As a corollary question, what about the sum

$$
\sigma(n)=\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{i^n j^{n-1}}?
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first sum equals
$$
\sum_{i,j}\frac1{i^nj^n}-\sum_{i=j}\frac1{i^nj^n}=\zeta(n)^2-\zeta(2n).$$

The same trick works for your the second sum.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What about the second case, i.e., when the $i$ and $j$ in the denominator have differing exponents?

Comment: As I say, the same trick works for your the second sum. @Flermat

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't notice that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{i\neq j} \frac{1}{i^n j^n}=\sum_{i} \frac{1}{i^n}\sum_{j} \frac{1}{ j^n}-\sum_{k} \frac{1}{k^{2n}}$$